# Where to locate singleton in node.js with modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, singleton

There are many questions about singleton pattern in javascript. All answers i found recommend:

- IIFE that produces a factory hidden in a closure. Then using that factory, we can call `getInstance()`
- to avoid relying on `require` (and node.js module) as a way of getting singleton.

but then we have to store that factory somewhere so it can be accessed by other modules. it can't be stored in any random module because then we rely on `require`. in such case it seems like the only ways to have safe singleton is to:

- store the factory in global variable or
- let top level script manage creation of the singleton instance (and pass it to other modules)

is one of them better than another? are there any other ways?

Comment: *to avoid relying on require (and node.js module) as a way of getting singleton* - which is a mistake. *it can't be stored in any random module because then we rely on require* - and why is this a problem?

Comment: @estus https://medium.com/@lazlojuly/are-node-js-modules-singletons-764ae97519af

Comment: The article contains correct facts but the conclusions are baseless. *Node’s module caching mechanism is case-sensitive* - filesystems are case-insensitive. *Modules are cached based on their resolved filename* - this can be used for good or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js already provides a way to produce singletons. CommonJS modules (the same applies to other JS modules) are evaluated once on their first import, so exported object remains a singleton. This is natural behaviour for the platform that can be used as a rule of thumb.

This behaviour of Node.js modules can be overridden by `require` cache mangling, e.g. [`decache`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decache). A possible use is testing. Another use case is hacking third-party NPM module to *not* produce a singleton if that's desirable behaviour, this would require to fork it otherwise.

> store the factory in global variable

The use of globals in modular environments is generally discouraged.

> let top level script manage creation of the singleton instance (and pass it to other modules)

This is dependency injection pattern. It can be used where needed but provides overhead if an application doesn't use the benefits of the pattern.